# What is the reason that you are not allowed to learn Torah shebictav at night?

Tags: halacha, tanach, torah-study, evening-night

I saw in some books (Rav Belsky, Arizal) that you are not allowed to learn torah Shebictav (Tanach) at night without commentaries. Why is that?

Comment: Did the books give any reasons? Which book by the Arizal or Rav Belsky?

Comment: no, i asked my friend he said something about demons harming you. I saw it in Rav Belskys halacha book. I heard it comes from Arizal the source.

Comment: Rav Belsky and Arizal?! That's a pretty interesting combination

Comment: Halachically Speaking has a chapter on this.

Comment: Rivevos Ephraim chelek 2:86

Comment: What about Tikkun Leil Shavuos and Tikkun Leil Hoshana Raba?

Comment: Note: them Torah Shebiktav almost always meant the Chumash in particular, in early sources.

Answer (score 15):

Mishne Berurah (238, Shaar HaTziyun 1) writes that the Midrash (Pirkei d'Rebbi Eliezer 46 and Tanchumah Parsha Ki Sisa 36) writes that Moshe Rabenu was taught the Written Torah during the day and the Oral Torah at night. From this Midrash the Ba'er Hetev (2) (and Arizal [ed]) concludes that one should not learn the written Torah at night.

The Pri Megadim writes that it is permissible to learn Torah Shebeksav at night and the Shaar Hatziyun concludes that even according to the *Machmirim* it is only a preference and not an issur.

Additionally, the Yesod veShoresh Ha'Avodah (6:2) writes that with a Peirush there is no problem at night in any event.

Regarding Tehillim (which is the Written Torah and according to Arizal should not studies at night), the Kaf Hachaim (237:9) writes the minhag is to recite it after Chatzos, But Aishel Avraham (Butchatch) writes there is no problem at night but then adds perhaps only with a minyan.

See Dirshu edition of Mishne Berurah, ibid) and also see Yabia Omer OC 17

Some add that Friday and Yom Tov evening is not problematic to learn Torah Shebeksav according to Arizal (Yosef Ometz 54). Some include Thursday night (going into Friday) as well (Yesod veshoresh ha'avodah and others. See Piskei teshuvos footnote 32)

Comment: Does the same apply to Oral Torah during the day?

Comment: @DoubleAA That's an interesting point! I did not see anywhere in my research not to learn Oral Torah during the day. My guess is that Oral Torah nearly always has a reference to Written Torah (cf Kiddusihin 30, Rabenu Tam in Tosfos sv Lo) and is therefore not problematic

Comment: דדער ספר חק לישראל איז א סדר פון דער וואכענדיגער סדרה, עס איז אזוי מסודר אז יעדן טאג פון דער וואך זאל מען לערנען אביסל חומש רש"י, נביאים, כתובים, משנה, גמרא, זוהר. חומש לערנט מען די וואכנדיגע סדרה, זונטיג 6 פסוקים, מאנטיג 4 פסוקים, דינסטיג 5 פסוקים, מיטוואך 6 פסוקים, דאנערשטיג 5 פסוקים, און מען איז משלים די סדרה ליל ששי און פרייטיג. נביאים לערנט מען די הפטרה אויפן זעלבן סדר.That seems to mean thursday night lail shishi as well.

Comment: @preferred Some permit that. I updated answer. This is a very large topic and I am obviously not including every opinion

Answer (score 8):

In the siddur of Rabbi Shabtai from Rashkov, which presents kavvanot of the Arizal (many books do, it's just the one I have at hand), it says, in the section 'Kriat Shma she-al Ha-Mita':

> אין ללמוד מקרא בלילה כי הקורא בלי פירוש עומדת בעשייה מקום תגבורת
>   הדינין ואין ראוי לעוררן בזמן שליטתן שהוא לילה
>
> One should not learn Miqra at night because reading [Miqra] without
>   commentary stands in [the world of] Asiyyah, the place of the
>   strengthening of the harsh judgements, and it is not proper to awaken
>   them at the time of their rule, at night.

For the Kabbalists, part of the rhythm of time is that during the first half of the night the forces of judgment are ascendant in the world of עשיה. Also, for the Kabbalists, different kinds of learning--e.g., learning Mishnah, learning Kabbalah, learning Miqra-- stand in different worlds. Since Miqra stands in עשיה, it shouldn't be engaged in at night.

Answer (score 1):

The Arizal taught that Mikra, Torah She’bichsav (the Written Torah) should not be read at night. However, translating the Chumash into any other language, and especially learning Chumash with the commentary of Rashi—which is Torah She’be’al Peh (the Oral Torah)—is permissible at night. Ideally, however, studying Chumash in any manner should preferably be done in the daytime.

Tehillim, according to many opinions, is also included in the Arizal’s enjoinment against Mikra at night, and therefore shouldn’t be recited in the nighttime either. It is the custom that even reciting Tehillim in the form of a techinah and bakashah (supplication)—according to some opinions, even for someone who is unwell— as opposed to studying it, should also be avoided at night.

Many poskim rule that all of the above does not apply after chatzos (midnight), particularly with regard to Tehillim. Certainly in a case of a choleh she’yesh bo sakanah (someone who is critically ill), G-d forbid, one may be lenient and say Tehillim at night, especially if it’s after chatzos.

שקו״ט בזה בכ״מ עפ״ד האריז״ל בשעהמ״צ פ׳ ואתחנן (וראה גם ריקאנטי פ׳ יתרו), והובא גם להלכה בבאה״ט או״ח סרל״ח סק״ב. וראה במשנ״ב שם בשעה״צ בריש הסימן.

והובאו בזה כמה צדדי קולא באחרונים, ואא״פ להעתיק בכאן כל הפרטים, כי קצר המצע מהשתרע. ולא באנו אלא להעיר במש״כ בכ״מ להקל בלומד עם פירוש, והביאו כן מיסוש״ה שער הששי פ״ב – שכ״כ גם בסי׳ ר׳ שבתי סדר השכיבה. ומובא כבר במ״ח מסכת השכיבה פ״א. (ובנוגע להמ״ח בכלל – ראה מה שכתבנו במ״מ וציונים להלכה יומית אות תצא ובהשמטות לשם). וראה שו״ת אבני צדק יו״ד סי׳ קב שהעיר כבר מזה. ומ״מ, לכתחילה עדיף טפי לפני הלילה גם בכה״ג – ראה אג״ק חי״ג ע׳ שלא.

ולהרחבת היריעה בכ״ז, הנה כל האר״ש לפניך, כנסמן בספרים דלקמן – שו״ת יבי״א ח״ו סי׳ ל. שם ח״ז סי״ז. שמירת הגוף והנפש ספ״ד. פסקי תשובות במקומו. הלכה ברורה (יוסף) שם ס״ד ואילך. בתורתו יהגה ח״ד פ״י. קובץ אור ישראל חו׳ טז ע׳ קל ואילך. ובקשתם משם.

והנה, ידוע מה שעלו ונסתפקו אחרונים חביבים אם תהלים הוא ג״כ בכלל אזהרת האריז״ל. וכמה סברות בדבר – שיתכן שמקרא (לעניננו) היינו רק חמשה חומשי תורה, או שאמירת תהלים נחשבת כנגעים ואהלות (ראה אצלנו במ״מ וציונים להלכה יומית אות שפב), וה״ז כלימוד תושבע״פ, או״י שבאומרו דרך שירות ותשבחות שאני. ולמעשה, נתפשטה ההוראה להחמיר גם באמירת תהלים, עכ״פ עד חצות הלילה, וכמ״ש בנימוקי או״ח סרל״ח, ובכ״מ – ראה בהנסמן לעיל. וראה גם הנסמן במאסף לכל המחנות ס״א סקל״ח. שו״ת יצחק ירנן ח״א סכ״ו. מנהגי החיד״א או״ח ח״א סכ״ב ס״ב. ומשם באר״ה.

ואדרבה, במדה מסויימת, אמירת תהילים – שאינה בגדר לימוד והוא ללא פירושה – חמורה יותר.

ועכצ״ל שבפסוקים שבסדר התפלה (ערבית, סדר ספה״ע, קידוש לבנה, קשעהמ״ט וכו׳, ודומה לקריאת המגילה בליל פורים ואיכה בליל ת״ב. ויתירה מזו, קריאת שמע של ערבית) לית לן בה – ראה עד״ז משמ״ש ס״מ סק״ו (גם לגבי שיעורי לימוד. ושם, בנוגע להשלמת השיעורים במוצאי ת״ב. ולהעיר משו״ת לבו״מ מהדו״ת או״ח סקפ״ו להתיר בכל שיעור קבוע. ועד״ז בשו״ת בית ישראל או״ח סל״ה. ובס׳ המנהגים ע׳ 20 (ובכ״מ באג״ק – נסמנו לקמן) שמנהגנו להקל בשיעור חומש היומי, אבל לא בתהילים היומי. אלא, שלכאו׳ ה״ט בזה, כיון שלימוד שיעור חומש היומי הוא עם פירש״י). נימוקי או״ח סרל״ח (בפסוקי דרחמי בקשעהמ״ט, שלהגן שאני. ושם עד״ז בנוגע לאמירת ד׳ מזמורים קודם השינה. ודלא כבא״א מבוטשאטש שם שאין תהילים בכלל. אבל ראה באג״ק דלקמן מזה). כה״ח סקל״ז סק״ב (תהלים קאפ׳ קכא בתפילת ערבית, למנהגם). שו״ת בצה״ח ח״ד סמ״ד.

ולא יוקשה בעיניך ממש״כ בשעה״כ (דרושי הלילה, תפילת ערבית בתחילתו) שהאריז״ל לא הי׳ אומר שום מזמור לפני ברכו כ״א ג׳ פסוקים – שהרי לא נתפרש שם בטעמא דמילתא מצד מקרא בלילה, והרי גם באמירת ג׳ פסוקים הנ״ל בעל כרחך ליישב כנ״ל. (אלא, שבלא״ה מובא בכ״מ שהאריז״ל התפלל לפני צאה״כ, ראה שע״ת סרל״ה סק״ב. אבל ראה נימוקי או״ח שם. והדברים עתיקים. ואכ״מ).

[והנה כי כן הוא גם במש״כ שם בשעה״כ בנוגע לאמירת מזמורים במוצ״ש. וסרה ההוכחה מכאן בהשקו״ט בנוגע למוצ״ש אם אפ״ל מקרא (ותהילים) או לא – דלאו מטעם זה קאתי עלה, שהרי בנדו״ז ה״ז מענינו של יום ומסדר התפילה].

ועוד, שכתב מהרש״ו בסידור חמדת ישראל (תפילת ערבית) לפרש מד״ע, שהוא לפי שסדר המזמורים הוא לסדר עולמות אבי״ע ובערבית א״צ לסדר זה. ולא עוד, אלא שכת״ש שהאומרם לא הפסיד כאדם הקורא בתורה, וכוונת הרב הי׳ לומר שאי״ב שום חיוב.

(ודעת אדה״ז בסידורו לומר מזמור שלם דוקא – הוא ע״ד הנגלה, בכדי שלא לומר קדיש על פסוקים מלוקטים (ראה פסקי הסידור בהערה לאות סה, ע״פ שע״א ש״י בפתחי שערים סקמ״ג. ולהעיר, שבסי׳ חמדת ישראל שם בדעת האריז״ל שאמר פסוקים הנ״ל, בכדי שלא לומר קדיש על דבר ריקם). ובטעם מזמור הנ״ל דוקא – ראה א״ר סוסי׳ רלז. ועוד. וראה גם בפע״ח שער מנחה וערבית).

וד״ז שייך גם לנשים – ראה שו״ת רב פעלים בסוד ישרים ח״א ס״ט. (אלא שבמש״כ לענין תיקון חצות – ראה כה״ח ס״א סקט״ו). וי״ח בזה.

לאידך, פשוט, שמי שאינו יודע כ״א מקרא או תהלים לא יתבטל מלימודו – ראה פתח עינים להחיד״א ברכות ג, ב. חסל״א סרל״ח סק“י. עיקרי הד״ט או״ח סכ״ב סקנ״ז בשם ככר לאדן להחיד״א (ונמצא הוא בככר לאדן לקוטים ס״ה סק״ג). בא״ח ש״א פקודי ס״ז. שו״ת מהרש״ם ח״א סקנ״ח. בצה״ח שם. ובאמת, כבר קדמם בח״י (שבת פח״י), וידוע שבד״כ העתיק מקודמיו (וראה המצויין אצלנו ע״ד זהותו,  במ״מ וציונים להלכה יומית אות תצא). וראה מש״כ להשיג עליו בשו״ת קציני ארץ סי״ג, שלע״ה גרע טפי, עיי״ש. וי״ל. ולהעיר שגם בכתהאריז״ל כתב רק ״אין ראוי לקרוא מקרא״, ולא לשון איסורא, ובכה״ג.

ולענין תהילים לחולה (לפני חצות) – רבו בזה הדעות והמנהגים. והנה, בשו״ת רב פעלים ח״ב ס״ב החמיר מאד, גם למקשה לילד וכה״ג. והחרה החזיק אחריו בשו״ת יבי״א הנ״ל (ולא נקט בכחא דהתירא, כדרכו). אבל ראה חזו״ע להנ״ל אבילות ח״א ע׳ יט. וראה גם בשו״ת צי״א ח״ח ע׳ סב. שם חי״ז ס״ג. בא״מ ח״ד סכ״ב. בצה״ח שם סמ״ו.

ואם כי דעת כו״כ מהנ״ל נוטה להקל – מצינו בכמה חוגים שנהגו להחמיר גם בכה״ג, וכדעת רב פעלים הנ״ל, ראה שו״ת אול״צ ח״ב פמ״ו סס״ד. תהילים אגרא דהילולי ע׳ קעט (מהרה״צ מנאסויד). אדיר במרום סקאליע אות שפז (ע׳ קפז). זכור לאברהם (קאהן) סס״ב סס״ז. וראה גם כמה עובדות עד״ז בס׳ תפארת בנים טויסיג על קיצשו״ע ס״א ס״ה (ע׳ כז). וראה זה פלא, שכן נהגו להחמיר גם בחוגי המוסר – ראה ס׳ זכרון בית קלם ע׳ כח.

ומה גם לפמש״כ באג״ק (חי״ט ע׳ שסט. וראה גם חכ״ב ע׳ כו) שצ״ע גם בנוגע לאמירת ד׳ מזמורי תהילים לפני השינה, אף שהוא להגן (ודלא כנימוקי או״ח הנ״ל). ומ״מ, בחושבי״ס כמדומה ברור שנהוג עלמא להקל.

ולענין תהילים כשמירה אצל בר מינן ל״ע – ראה הנסמן בשו״ת יבי״א שם שהקלו בזה. וכמדומה שכן המנהג בכ״מ. לאידך, בשו״ת חיים שאל ח״ב סכ״ה כתב החיד״א להחמיר בהקפות למת בליל מוצש״ק מה״ט. ושקו״ט בדעת החיד״א, במנהגי החיד״א שם. וכ״ה במנהגי המקובלים בקונט׳ החיים יודוך ש״ב (ע׳ עא) לומר רק משניות לפני חצות.

ומעתה, בנוגע ללילי שויו״ט – הנה בליל שישי כ׳ להדיא בשעהמ״צ להתירא. ועפ״ז כ׳ בשו״ת יוסף אומץ להחיד״א סנ״ד, שהדברים ק״ו בליל שבת. וכ״ה בכ״מ. (ויש שהוסיפו גם בנוגע למוצ״ש, וכנ״ל. ואכ״מ). ועפ״ז כתבו כו״כ להקל גם בנוגע ליל יו״ט (שו״ת מהרש״ם ח״א סקנ״ח ד״ה הנה. רב פעלים שם. בא״ח (להנ״ל) שם. ואפי׳ בנוגע לחוה״מ – ראה שו״ת לבו״מ מהדו״ת או״ח סקפ״ו). וראה שו״ת שיח יצחק או״ח סקט״ז.

אמנם, בארצה״ח ס״א בהמאיר לארץ סקל״ו כ׳ עפ״ד המקובלים (ויתכן שכוונתו לח״י ענין יוהכ״פ פ״ד) להתיר ביוהכ״פ כמו בשבת, לפי שהוא שבת שבתון מלא רצון לה׳. וא״כ אין הכרח בנוגע לשאר יו״ט. [ולהעיר, שע״פ דא״ח, ביו״ט יש קצת יניקה ולכן מותר במלאכת או״נ משא״כ בשבת – ראה סידור עם דא״ח סעודת ליל שבת)].

וממש״א תושב״כ בסדר תיקון ליל שבועות – אין ראי׳, לפי שהוא מסדר היום. ועו״כ לחלק באו״א, ראה הנסמן בקובץ אור ישראל שם (הע׳ 11). וממוצא דבריהם אתה למד לכאו׳, שהחמירו גם בליל יו״ט. וראה גם ע״פ דא״ח, בטעם מה שליל שבועות הוא להיפך מכל השנה, תושב״כ קודם חצות ושבע״פ אחרי חצות, במאמרי אדמו״ר האמצעי במדבר ח״ב דרושי שבועות ע׳ שכו ואילך. וראה הנסמן בהערות המו״ל שם לכו״כ דרושים עד״ז. ולהעיר מאג״ק חי״ג ע׳ קלג.

והנה, באג״ק דלקמן, בכל המקומות, נז׳ רק להקל בר״ה יוהכ״פ, והושע״ר. (ובאג״ק חכ״ב ע׳ רצב: מלבד ביום הכפורים וכיו״ב, ובס׳ המנהגים הנ״ל נזכר גם עשי״ת. ומה שהביאו עד״ז מא״א מבוטשאטש או״ח סש״ו במוצאי יום ב׳ דר״ה – לשי׳ קאזיל להתיר באמירת תהילים, כנ״ל, ובפרט לחולה). ומ׳ ג״כ דלא שמיעא לן להתיר בכל לילי יו״ט.

ועפ״ז, ראיתי לכמה חכמים שכתבו שמנהגנו להחמיר גם בליל שבת. אלא שהדבר תמוה, היאך אפ״ל להקל בליל שישי, ולהחמיר בליל שבת. וגם צ״ע לומר שלימוד מקרא בליל שבת מעורר דינים – שהרי כל דינין מתעברין מינה, ואין כאן בית מיחוש. ובקושטא י״ל שלא נחית כ״א לפרט החידוש בנוגע לליל ר״ה ויוהכ״פ, משא״כ בליל שבת, שפשוט להיתרא. (וראה מפי השמועה בספר דיני ומנהגי ר״ח ע׳ ז הע׳ 26).  ועדיין, דבר ההשמטה אומר דרשני.

אמנם כן, של׳ הפע״ח שער הנהגת הלימוד הוא ש״יש קצת מציאות שיוכל לקרוא מקרא״ בליל שישי. ומשמע שאי״ז היתר מרווח, וקאי רק על קריאת כ״ו פסוקים שנזכרו שם. ועד״ז הוא בנגיד ומצוה ס׳ תיקון חצות. (וראה גם היום יום ד׳ טבת). [ולהעיר שיש שכתבו ללמוד כ״ו פסוקים רק אחרי חצות הלילה]. ואכן יש שכתבו כן למעשה, שאין לקרוא בליל שישי כ״א כ״ו פסוקים הנ״ל, ראה מה שהאריך בשו״ת וישב הים ס״ו סק״ה.

ולהעיר, שבשעהמ״צ שם כ׳ בנוגע לליל ו׳ שאין לכוון במילוי הוי׳ דההי״ן כמו בה׳ ימי השבוע, ״שהמילוי היא דין ואין ראוי לעורר דינים״.

ועדיין לא איפרק מחולשא, דבשעהמ״צ שם (מז, א): ואח״כ תקרא מה שתרצה כמנהגך, ומ׳ גם מקרא (ונקט ל׳ ״תקרא״). ויתירה מזו, בהמשך דבריו (מח, א) כ׳ בפשי׳ שבליל ששי יכול לקרוא מקרא אף בלילה, ולא קאי התם כלל בענין כ״ו פסוקים.

ועוד ועיקר, דאנן בליל שבת קיימינן השתא, והיאך אפ״ל שיש להימנע מקריאת מקרא אז, שכולו רחמים פשוטים. ואף שביום, ובפרט בעת רעוא דרעוין, הוא תכלית הרחמים ולית דינין דתקיפין, ועוד שבלילה אומרים ברכת מעי״ז מפני המזיקין – מ״מ, גם בליל שבת לית דין ולית דינא. וק״ו שמעלתו גדולה מליל ששי, ומיום הששי.

איברא, שמצינו לגורי האריז״ל (והובא גם בשע״ת סרפ״ה סק״א) שכתבו שלא לומר תרגום בלילה שלא להגביר מדה״ד, ועכ״ז כתבו ג״כ שלא לומר תרגום בשבת ויו״ט.

אלא שבנוגע לשויו״ט אאפ״ל שהוא מטעם הנ״ל, שהרי כתבו שלא לאומרו גם ביום ש״ק. ונתפרש הטעם במעין גנים להרמ״ע מפאנו (א, ד) באו״א, כיון שבשויו״ט המלכות, בחי׳ תרגום, נכללת בזכר, בחי׳ מקרא. וא״כ אי״ז שייך כלל לעניננו.

ומ״מ, ראה בשו״ת וישב הים שם סק״ז שהאריך להוכיח בדעת האריז״ל שאף שאין לחוש בקריאת התרגום שמעורר דינים בשבת, מ״מ אינו ראוי לקרוא תרגום בליל שבת בזמן שהרחמים גוברים. ומה שקרא האריז״ל שמו״ת בליל שבת – היינו כשלא קרא בע״ש, וגם שהוא לצורך פרצוף הנתקן באותו יום, עיי״ש באורך.

ומדאתינן להכי, ה״ה שי״ל שלא לקרוא מקרא בליל שבת, אף שאינו כ״כ בחי׳ הדינים כבתרגום, ורק בקריאת שמו״ת. ולהעיר גם שבכה״ח סרל״ז סק״ט כ׳: ומשמע שם בשעהמ״צ דבליל שויו״ט אין לחוש, עיי״ש. ונראה מדבריו דלא ברירא לי׳ מילתא כ״כ. ועצ״ע בכ״ז.

[ונוסף לכהנ״ל, ילה״ע מצד גזירת קריאת כתובים בשבת מצד ביטול ביהמ״ד. וראה וילקט יוסף חו׳ יד סק״ח שר״ל שכ״ה גם בליל ש״ק. וראה שלחן מנחם ח״ב סרט״ו בנוגע לקריאת המגילות בשבתות של ג׳ הרגלים].

ולהעיר שגם בהושע״ר נהגו באמירת תהילים רק אחרי חצות. וראה בל׳ ספר המנהגים דלעיל. ובפשטות, לפי שאז הוא זמן מסוגל לאמירת תהילים. וכ״כ בשיחת ליל הושע״ר תשמ״ט. ולהעיר מר״ד הושע״ר תשכ״ז.

זמן התחלת הלילה לענין זה – בכ״מ כתבו מצאה״כ דייקא, ושבביהשמ״ש יש להקל. וראה שו״ת מי יהודא או״ח סכ״ב. לאידך בח״י הנז׳ כ׳ משקיעה״ח. ובאג״ק דלקמן נמצא לכאן ולכאן. ושקו״ט בזה רבים ושלמים. ואולי יש לחלק לפי הענין. וכגון בהשלמת השיעורים בדיעבד, ואין דנין אפשר מאא״פ, או בהתחיל ביהשמ״ש שיש שכתבו להקל בכה״ג. ועוד כיו״ב.

זמן סיום הלילה – בכ״מ אי׳ שהוא עד אשמורת הבוקר. וי״א רק עד חצות. וראה הנסמן בספרים דלעיל, בפתח דברינו. אלא, שבתהילים נתפשט המנהג להקל לאחרי חצות. ובאג״ק חי״ג ע׳ שלא: ״ידוע מש״כ בכתהאריז״ל שאין ללמוד מקרא בלילה. כן נזהרים מאמירת תהלים בלילה עד חצות״. ובפשטות, הכוונה כאן בשתים: שאף שנסתפקו בתהלים אם הוא בכלל אזהרת האריז״ל, בפועל נזהרים גם מזה, כנ״ל. לאידך, בתהילים נזהרים רק עד חצות ותו לא, משא״כ במקרא בכלל. והארכנו מזה בקובץ הארבעים (קרית גת). והנת׳ כאן – עיקר. (ולהעיר משיחת ש״פ תבוא תשל״ד בנוגע למקרא אחר חצות).

Comment: enight please be more pedagogic. give an abstract in hebrew, translated i English. the end of the post should be the conclusion, in e clear way.
"אלא שבנוגע לשויו״ט אאפ״ל שהוא מטעם הנ״ל, שהרי כתבו שלא לאומרו גם ביום ש״ק. ונתפרש הטעם במעין גנים להרמ״ע מפאנו (א, ד) באו״א, כיון שבשויו״ט המלכות, בחי׳ תרגום, נכללת בזכר, בחי׳ מקרא. וא״כ אי״ז שייך כלל לעניננו."
אתה לא חושב שאתה מגזים או שאתה סבור שאנשים יקראו הכל. תתמצט, תגיד מה שיש לך להגיד ותסביר לעצמך בדיוק מי הוא קהל היעד שלך. למרות שזה הנאה לכתוב ולהתפתלפל בכל זאת אתה פונה לציבור מסוים ואתה חייב לכבד אותו.