# Why is kedusha only said during the day?

Tags: tefilla, evening-night, kedusha-prayer

The *kedusha* is said as part of the morning blessings of *shema*, and also in all the public recital of prayers. It's not said in the evening prayer, neither in the blessings before *shema* nor the prayer itself.

Is there any reason why it's only mentioned in the liturgy (*shema*, *shemone esre*) during the day and not at night? Could it be that the angels only say the prayer during the day? Or is it related to the practice [not to learn written Torah at night](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27923/1569)? Or some other reason?

(The *kedusha desidra* is said sometimes at night, but for [a different reason](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1250), and [rumor has it](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/90169/1569) that even then some specifically say the verses quietly.)

Comment: Well, it can't be in Shemoneh Esrei, because there's no Chazaras HaShatz for Maariv. The other ones are still valid.

Comment: @DonielF I'm not totally sure about that. Technically you only need 10 people to say it as a דבר שבקדושה, but on the other hand an individual can't say it, so it might only be an option for public mandatory prayers

Comment: I surmise that saying kedusha during the day is related to the idea of the angle that wrestled with Ya'akov all night and when dayllight struck, he says, "Let me go because it's daylight." Rash"i says "...and I must praise G-d". No proof to this theory, but I wouldn't be surprised that it has something to do with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr - it's kabbalah (likely), or it's to reject karaites (highly unlikely), it's coincidental because the evening prayer is optional (very likely).**

To me, the most likely option is that this is based on Kabbalah, although for the opposite reason of what you suggest (not because angels only say it during the day, but because they only say it at night).  [Zohar (Shemos 1:2, commentary to Shemos 2:1)](http://www.kab.co.il/heb/content/view/frame/21794?/heb/content/view/full/21794&main) tells us that the angels sing "shirah" (which is likely Kedusha, for a number of reasons) only at night, and listen to people singing shirah during the day:

> וילך איש מבית לוי ויקח את בת לוי, רבי אלעזר פתח, (שיר א א) שיר השירים אשר לשלמה, תנא כשברא הקדוש ברוך הוא את עולמו, עלה בחפץ לפניו וברא את השמים בימינו, והארץ בשמאלו, ועלה בחפץ לפניו לנהוג היום והלילה, וברא המלאכים הממונים בחסדו ביום, (נ"א לומר שירה ביום זמן החסד), וברא המלאכים הממונים לומר שירה בלילה, הדא הוא דכתיב (תהלים מב ט) יומם יצוה יהו"ה חסדו ובלילה שירה עמי, אלו מימין ואלו משמאל, אלו מקשיבים שירת היום, ואלו מקשיבים שירת הלילה, שירתם של ישראל קדוש. רבי יצחק אמר, אותם שאומרים שירה בלילה, מקשיבים שירתם של ישראל ביום, הדא הוא דכתיב (שיר ח יג) חברים מקשיבים לקולך.

Or, [Aspaklaria's](http://www.aspaklaria.info/040_MEM/%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%9A%20%20%20%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%94.htm) explained version of the Zohar, which clarifies these points:

> ברא המלאכים והממונים לומר שירה בלילה, (כי השירה היא סוד הארת חכמה הנמשכת על ידי הנוקבא הנקראת לילה), זה שאמר יומם יצוה ה' חסדו (על ידי המלאכים הממונים על החסד), ובלילה שירה עמי, (על ידי המלאכים הממונים על השירה), ואלו (שמימין), מקשיבים שירת היום, שירתם של ישראל קדושים, (כי ישראל אומרים שירה ביום), רבי יצחק אמר, אותם שאומרים שירה בלילה מקשיבים שירתם של ישראל ביום, זהו שכתוב חברים מקשיבים לקולך.

Or, [Zohar La'am's version](http://www.kab.co.il/heb/content/view/frame/92749?/heb/content/view/full/92749&main):

> כמ"ש, יומם יצווה ה' חסדו, ע"י המלאכים הממונים על החסד. ובלילה שירה עימי, ע"י המלאכים הממונים על השירה. מימין הממונים על החסד, משמאל הממונים על השירה. ואלו שמימין מקשיבים שירת היום, שירתם של ישראל קדושים. כי ישראל אומרים שירה ביום. אותם שאומרים שירה בלילה, מקשיבים שירתם של ישראל ביום, כמ"ש, חברים מקשיבים לקולך.

Such sentiments are repeated in [Hechalos Rabbasi 10:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Hechalot_Rabbati.10.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) (which is [understood](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%94_(%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94)#%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%94) to be the kabbalistic source for why/when/how we say "kedusha"), which notes that we only say kedusha during Shacharis and Mincha:

> לי שמים וארץ ויורדי מרכבה אם כרובים תגידו זה אמרו לכלימה אני עושה בתפלת שחרית ובתפלת המנחה בכל יום בכל שעה שישראל אומרים קדוש קדוש קדוש ה' ולמדו אותן ואמרו להם שאו עיניכם לרקיע כנגד בית תפלתכם בשעה שאתם אומרים קדוש קדוש קדוש ה' צבאות וגו':

See also [10:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Hechalot_Rabbati.10.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), which calls our reciting of "kadosh kadosh kadosh..." a "shirah".

As a follow-up to this, [Aruch Hashulchan (OC 236:3)](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%9C%D7%96) and others say clearly that the reasons of not saying Kedusha at night are due to Kabbalah, perhaps the above:

> אך באמת יש טעמים נסתרים על מה שאין חזרת הש"ץ בלילה ואין אומרים קדושה בלילה ורק הש"ץ אומר קדיש שלם ואומרים עלינו וקדיש יתום ונפטרים לבתיהם לשלום

Also see Eshel Avraham (Butchach) OC 232:1, who ties this in to quasi-Kabbalah for a slightly different reason than we presented (saying kadosh and baruch at night and day), but still allows one to recite Kedusha of Mincha after Tzeis Hakochavim, because he ultimately admits that one can get around his quasi-kabbalistic issue, so I won't discuss it at length.

Rav Tzadok (Sichas Malachei Hashares 4, cited [here](http://www.aspaklaria.info/010_YOD/%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%AA%20%D7%94.htm)) presents a super-kabbalistic explanation for not saying kedusha at night.  From what I understand, since it's night, we don't have the proper recognition of Hashem to say that His honor is blessed from His place (which is apparently localized), but only to say that the honor of His kingdom is blessed, since that is everywhere always:

> וזהו כבוד מלכותו ולא כבוד ה' שכבוד ה' אינו מלא הארץ רק במקומו ושיהיה ברוך ממקומו ויתברך כבוד מלכותו הניכר בארץ שהוא מצד השגת ה' הנעלמת להיות מושגת הבירור מצד היראה הברורה שבלב. רק תפשפש באפילה ובדרך אמוניי כדרך שנאמר (תהלים צ"ב, ג') ואמונתך בלילות בעת חשכת ליל שאין אומרים קדושה בלילה שאז הוא חושך והעדר ההכרה הברורה ומשכה אז האמונה הטמונה בלב כל איש ישראל. שיש מלך אף על פי שאינו עומד לפניו שאז הוא כאדון העומד על עבדו ואב על בנו רק כמלך יושב בהיכלו. ומצד השגה באופן זה שהוא המכונה בזוהר ובפי חכמי האמת יחודא תתאה והשגה נעלמת ושפילה. היא הברוך והבקשה ממקומו שיהיה בזה תוספת וריבוי עד שיהיה ניכר ומושג לשפילים:

---

Alternatively, it seems possible that this was to distance us from the Karaites. In [this Karaite Siddur](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Gm8_AAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA21&dq=%22%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%20%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%20%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%22%20%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94&pg=PA10#v=onepage&q&f=false) (page 10/5b), they appear to have a prayer based around "kadosh" and "baruch" that they say specifically at nights. However, that may just as easily be a Karaite response to us saying it only during the day (this is here just because it's cool).

---

Now for some real halachic sources that show that there is no concern:

The notes to Yalkut Yosef (OC 233 note 8) clearly say that there is no issue whatsoever with saying kedusha at night, and it wasn't added for ma'ariv since ma'ariv is only a reshus (i.e. it has a lesser status), and therefore, if someone hears kedusha after ma'ariv, they should certainly answer:

> דהא דקיימא לן שאין קדושה בלילה, אינו בשביל שיש איסור לומר קדושה בלילה, אלא משום דערבית רשות ולא תקינו לומר קדושה. ולכן השומע קדושה מהצבור אחר שהתפלל ערבית, רשאי לענות קדושה.

This is said by Rav Ovadia Yosef himself in Yabia Omer 6:OC:21, note 4, and I direct you there (as well as the previous teshuvah) for a full halachic analysis, which I will not repeat here, but suffice it to say that there is another whole boatload of sources from all sorts of mainstream places. I will leave you with one early example (Ra'avan Berachos 169):

> ומדלא תקינו קדושה בתפילת ערבית כמו בשחרית ובשאר תפילות ש"מ שהוא רשות כר' יהושע, ואפי' בערב שבת שתיקנו לש"צ לומר ברכה אחת מעין שבע לא תיקנו לומר קדושה דרשות היא

Comment: *it's kabbalah (likely)* and *it's coincidental and not a rule (very likely)* indicates that it is **more** likely that it's not a rule than that it's kabbalah. But then you say *To me, the most likely option is that this is based on Kabbalah* which indicates the opposite. Or are you differentiating between objective likelihood and subjective likelihood to **you**?

Comment: @Alex No need to be medayek in my words. I wrote this over a while, before and after I may have seen different sources. If I was being medayek anyways, I would assume that I probably meant that if such a shitah exists (that it is prohibited to say kedusha at night), it is likely due to Kabbalah, while if I had to choose between "coincidental and not a rule" and "kabbalah", I would choose the former (or, eilu v'eilu, but I understand one better) (or, both are practiced by different communities).  But you can edit the lashon to correct it...

Comment: I don't see "it's coincidental and not a rule" in this answer? Maybe instead of coincidental you meant because the evening prayer is optional? Also, where can the boatload of sources be found?

Comment: @ba 1. I should have been clearer about that. The evening prayer is optional, and as a result of the not-instituted kedusha, not saying kedusha at night is coincidental, but not a rule. However, as some poskim note, Neilah which enters "night" would still have kedusha said... However, I get how the lashon could be misleading; feel free to clean it up. 2. The boatload of sources is in R' Ovadiah's teshuvah, I'll try to detail them later if you wish.

Comment: And as a postscript, it seems that the reason from the Zohar answers also why we don't say it in the blessings for shema, but the halachic reason of the prayer being optional only answers why we don't say it in the prayer itself